# unfortunately the application has stopped

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to list the files in the sdcard and sort them according to last modified date.

I dont get any errors when I build it but when I start it in emulator logcat shows an error and the emulator show "*unfortunately the application has stopped*".
Please help me understand the error message and how to solve this.

Here is the code I use:

main activity.java 
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public final class ComparatorImplementation implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object f1, Object f2)
    {
      if (((File) f1).lastModified() < ((File) f2).lastModified())
      {
        return -1;
      }
      else if (((File) f1).lastModified() > ((File) f2).lastModified())
      {
        return 1;
      }
      else
      {
        return 0;
      }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);


    File dir = new File("/storage/sdcard/");

    if(dir.isDirectory())
    {
      // Fetching the list from the directory
      File[] files = dir.listFiles();

      // Sort files by date.
     Arrays.sort(files, new ComparatorImplementation());

      //Prints files in order by last modified date
      for(File file:files)
      {
          info.setText( "list of files according to last modified date \n " + file.getName());
      }
    }       
    }
}
```

This is the logcat output

```
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399): Process: com.listfiles, PID: 3399
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity          ComponentInfo{com.listfiles/com.listfiles.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2023)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at com.listfiles.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at                       android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-14 01:58:10.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Line at `MainActivity.java:55` ?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullPointerException`. This means object is not initialized properly.

You can see that there is one line `at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2023)`, so I guess problem is in `Arrays.sort()` function.

I think there is some problem with following code

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();

// Sort files by date.
Arrays.sort(files, new ComparatorImplementation());
```

[`listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) can return `null` if the directory is invalid.

Try following code to prevent exception:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();

// Sort files by date.
if(files!=null){
    Arrays.sort(files, new ComparatorImplementation());

    //your rest of the code based on "files" object. If object is `null`, you can
    //not proceed
}
```

You should also use the method [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) instead of specifying it manually, as some devices has different paths to the sd-card.

Comment: thank you it worked...can u please tell me how to     [link] Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  instead of ma code line     `code` File dir = new File("/storage/sdcard/");

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you. It would be another pleasure if you accept the answer. I am giving you another example how to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.. :)

Comment: sir I'm using setText to list the file names the code is ` info.setText("list of files after sorting \n " + child.getName()); `  it is showing error as The method setText(CharSequence, TextView.BufferType) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Comment: use `child.getName().toString()` function. `info.setText("list of files after sorting \n " + child.getName().toString());`

Comment: Hello Sir I used your `code` Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in my app to list the files in external sdcard.But when i install the apk in ma mobile and run means its showing only one file even though there are many files.please help

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

files variable is set to null so it is crashing. Check before sorting if files is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

that's possible there were no file there.
you should check if there is any one with something like:

```
if (Dir.exists()) {
    // type your code here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arun you are not handling the file

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files, new ComparatorImplementation());
```

case:- suppose if dir path does exist,
case:- suppose if dir doesn;t contain the files
       then,files object is null,and it obviously throws null pointer exception, and what exactly happening here

solution: 
   handle files null pointer condition by:

```
if(files==null){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"directory doesnt contain files",0).show();}
else{
for(File file:files)
  {
      info.setText( "list of files according to last modified date \n " + file.getName());
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `listFiles()` which can be null if this file is not a directory.

I can see here:

```
File dir = new File("/storage/sdcard/");
```

And then,

```
dir.listFiles();
```

> **public File[] listFiles()**
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Returns an array of
>   files contained in the directory represented by this file. The result
>   is null if this file is not a directory. The paths of the files in the
>   array are absolute if the path of this file is absolute, they are
>   relative otherwise.
>
> Returns an array of files or null.